# how to change value of Navbar title in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navbar, react-bootstrap

I just learn react, and I try make a website with Bootstrap. 
Suppose below picture is my web page.
When I browse a link that path is "/project/react" the top left (value of Navbar title is "React"), then I browse a link that path is "/project/bootstrap" I hope the top left (value of Navbar title is "Bootstrap"). Is that possible? 
Because I got the title still show "React". 
Thank you

```
//MyPage.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MyNavbar from '../components/MyNavbar';
import MyReact from '../components/MyReact';
import MyBootstrap from '../components/MyBootstrap';

let pgName = "My Page"
class MyPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageName: pgName
    };
  }

  setPageName = (pageName) => {
    pgName = pageName;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ pageName: pgName });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyNavbar pageTitle={this.state.pageName}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/project/bootstrap" component={MyBootstrap} render={this.setPageName("Bootstrap")}/>
          <Route path="/project/react" component={MyReact} render={this.setPageName("React")}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default ProjectPage;


//MyNavbar.js
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Scrollchor from 'react-scrollchor';

class MyNavbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageTitle: props.pageTitle
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props,state){
    this.setState({ pageTitle: props.pageTitle });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar bg="dark " expand="lg" fixed="top">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className="menu-title">{this.state.projectTitle}</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" position="absolute" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="ml-auto" >
            <Scrollchor to="#docs" animate={{ offset: -90, duration: 300 }} className="nav-link">Docs</Scrollchor>
            <Scrollchor to="#tutorial" animate={{ offset: -90, duration: 300 }} className="nav-link">Tutorial</Scrollchor>
            <Scrollchor to="#blog" animate={{ offset: -90, duration: 300 }} className="nav-link">Blog</Scrollchor>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default MyNavbar;


//MyReact.js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import React from 'react';

class MyReact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>React</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default MyReact;


//MyBootstrap.js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import React from 'react';

class MyBootstrap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default MyBootstrap;
```

[image: example page]

Comment: Route render is an alternative to component: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: @FunkeyFlo thank you. Do you have another way to do that? Should I make the Navbar to be a component?

Answer (score 0):

Why calling setPageName in render prop?
according to react document, a render prop is a function prop that a component uses to know what to render.
In this case no need to use render prop just need an onClick function because you just want to change the title of previous rendered Navbar.
Second remember to add setState in your setPageName function, unless DOM would not be aware of state change neither the corresponding props.
Then when you change the pageName state navbar props will react to the change.

```
<Route path="/project/react" component={MyReact}  onClick={() => setPageName (someValue)} />

setPageName = (newPageName) =>{ setState({pageName : newPageName }) }
```

wish it will help

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

Pass a callback to the component as a prop

```js
<Route
  path="/project/bootstrap"
  render={(props) => <MyBootstrap {...props} isAuthed={true} setPageName={this.setPageName.bind(this)} />}
/>
```

Call the callback when the component is mounted

```js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import React from 'react';

class MyBootstrap extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { setPageName } = this.props;
    if(typeof setPageName === 'function) {
      setPageName('Bootstrap');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not be correct and is untested, but have you tried this?:

```
     <Route path="/project/bootstrap" component={MyBootstrap} render={() => this.setPageName("Bootstrap")}/>
      <Route path="/project/react" component={MyReact} render={() => this.setPageName("React")}/>
```

I think this is more likely to work, that way your `setPageName` function is only running on render.

Comment: As mentioned before; `render` is an alternative to `component`, not a way to provide a callback when a route is matched.